# Using CASE expression in QGIS data defined properties

Tags: qgis

I try to use CASE expression in my data defined properties, like this:

```
CASE WHEN  "ASULKM1999" > 100000 THEN 5 END
```

ASUKASLKM is population information and "5" will be size of point symbol. However, when I click ok/apply, QGIS will turn this expression to funny, like

```
CONDITION:
- WHEN ASULKM1999 > 100000 THEN 5
```

And nothing happens. Sometimes result is "(no root)".

Is this a bug / feature or am I doing something wrong? Using QGIS 2.1 master on Win and Ubuntu.

Rgs

P

Add some snapshots:

Start from here:

[image: Start from here:]

Define expression for Size-property:

[image: Define expression for Size-property]

Expression seems to be allright:

[image: Expression seems to be allright]

Click ok and then re-opening Data Defined properties:

[image: Re-opening Data Defined properties]

Expression is quite odd:

[image: Expression is quite odd]

Comment: Where does it change the text.  Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Wow that's a bit strange. I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok seems like a bug in 2.1 but 2.0 is ok.

Comment: Oops, I didn't check this on older version. Should I wrote a bug report or is this already fixed?

Comment: All good. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This was bug in QGIS 2.1 (master). Will work on version 2.0.

Fix is under a construction.

P